# inline 2 spans inside div

Tags: html, css

html

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <span>Visit website</span>
        <span>View project</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
    background-color: green;
}

div { padding: 0 20px; width: 0px; background:red;overflow:visible;  text-align: center;}

span {
    background:#222;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;

    margin:10px 10px 0 0;
    padding:5px 10px
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/cePe3/445/

---

How to make the 2 span to be inline with each other in the middle of the container DIV!

**Note:** code structure must be as its.

thank you

Comment: why is width: 0 for div ?

Comment: to animate the div starting from 0

Comment: As Krishna mentioned, it's all about the width of that div. You want the contained plain Div to provide some sort of visual flair (the red background) but you can't forget that it also serves to contain the spans within. The way you style the div will affect what happens to those spans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a more modern solution: [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

Add `display: flex; justify-content: center;` to **#container** and to **#container div**. It's magic.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cePe3/448/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your div width to auto

```
div { padding: 0 20px; width: auto; background:red;overflow:visible;  text-align: center;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cePe3/446/

Answer (score 0):

you have to set div width for inline span

```
div 
{ padding: 0 20px; 
  width: 350px;
  background:red;
  overflow:visible; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2fx6f2fz/)

Answer (score 0):

make the position absolute for the spans, then add jquery to center the spans, even on resizing of the window:

```js
$( window ).resize(function() {
    shuffle();
});

function shuffle() {
    $('span').each(function(){
        $(this).css('left',($('#container').width()-$(this).width()) / 2);
    });
    $('#container').find('div').css('height',$('span:first').height()*6);
}

shuffle();
```

```css
#container {
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
    background-color: green;
}

div { padding: 0 20px; width: 0px; background:red;overflow:visible;  text-align: center;}

span {
    position: absolute;
    background:#222;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;

    margin:10px 10px 0 0;
    padding:5px 10px
}

span:nth-child(2) {
    top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <span>Visit website</span>
        <span>View project</span>
    </div>
</div>
```